# Grouping and Getting Count with Lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I'm running into a roadblock and cant figure out how to get the count of a field. I'm aware of _.countBy and _.size that are available through Lodash, but for some reason cant come up with the correct values. The subgroup.items array contains values formatted as such:

```
{
  store name: 'A',
  sku title: '12345'
},
{
  store name: 'A',
  sku title: 09865
},
{
  store name: 'A',
  sku title: 63542
}
```

My block of code is this:

```
subGroup.items = _.chain(subGroup.items)
  .groupBy('store name')
  .map(function(v, i) {
    return {
       store: i,
       sku: _.reduce(
         v,
         function(res, val) {
           return res + val['sku title'];
         },
       0
     ),
  };
 })
.value();
```

How can I return values so that it would show how many sku title's there are for each store like this...

```
store name: 'A',
sku title: '3'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is a count, you should just be able to use `v.length` instead of using `_.reduce(v,...)`

```js
var subGroup = {};
subGroup.items = [{
  "store name": 'A',
  "sku title": '12345'
},
{
  "store name": 'A',
  "sku title": 09865
},
{
  "store name": 'A',
  "sku title": 63542
}];


subGroup.items = _.chain(subGroup.items)
  .groupBy('store name')
  .map(function(v, i) {
    return {
       store: i,
       sku: v.length
  };
 })
.value();

console.log(subGroup.items);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```